# where clause on query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch amount which not = 0

my query

```
select c.c_name, sum(cp.invoice_amount)-sum(cp.recived_amount) as amount from customer_payments cp
inner join customer c on c.c_id = cp.customer_id group by c.c_name
```

from which I am getting result of all customer that also having 0 amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your looking for the `HAVING` command

add this to the end

```
having amount <> 0
```